# Why implement condition variable?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix

I need help with the understanding of the mechanism of condition variable.

I understood that it uses functions: wait, timedwait, signal, broadcast.

When the "wait" or "timedwait" function called, the ID of current thread is append to the variable. Then, in an infinity loop, checked a some event (or the end of the time interval).

The "signal" and "broadcast" functions send a signal from resuming threads(one or more), that are written in the variable.

Roughly, condition variable is a struct:

```
struct cond_var{
    int thread_id[];
};
```

I hope I'm right.

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? I'm not sure whether you're telling or asking. Please [edit] your post rather than replying in a comment, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a (so-called) 'condition variable' is essentially a queue of suspended threads.

Yes, if there are any suspended threads, 'signal' will restart one or more of them and 'broadcast' will start all of them.  If there are no suspended threads, 'signal' and 'broadcast' have no effect.

Yes, there is no other state associated with the 'condition variable'.

Answer (score 0):

> Why...?

From the P.O.V. of an application programmer, condition variables are a *low-level, primitive* mechanism provided by the OS that can be used in the construction of many different, higher-level synchronization objects.

- If you're implementing a blocking queue, you could use one condition variable to notify consumers when the queue becomes non-empty, and you could use another to notify producers when the queue becomes non-full
- If you're implementing a semaphore, you could use a condition variable to notify waiting threads when a permit has been released.
- If you're implementing a barrier of some kind, you could use a condition variable to notify waiting threads that the barrier has "opened."
- Etc.